# Trying to insert post permalink in echo of the wordpress posts

Tags: php, wordpress

```
<?php the_permalink(); ?>
```

in the echo, so when the post title is clicked it opens it is respective post link, but on click of post title it is opening this link http://localhost/courses/, Here is my code

```
echo '<p><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">'.$post->post_title.'</a></p>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring PHP code within PHP code. Remove `<?PHP ?>` declaration tags, as they are not needed, and replace with string combine which is `.` in PHP.

End result should be:

```
echo '<p><a href="'. get_permalink() .'">'.$post->post_title.'</a></p>';
```

As mentioned in the other answer, [get_permalink()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_permalink/) should be used, as it returns not echos. [the_permalink()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_permalink/) echos the return.

Comment: syntax error, unexpected '.' giving me this error

Comment: it is displaying the link, i want to add post title to the link

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `the_permalink`.

As a general rule (not always correct), `the_` will echo, `get_` will return.

So in your case change `the_permalink()` to `get_permalink()`

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<p><a href="'. get_permalink() .'">'.$post->post_title.'</a></p>';
```

This code is working, Thankyou